# Circle Area C++ Truncation Calculation Problem

Tags: c++, math, geometry, console-application, truncation

I tried to make a console application in C++ that calculates the area of a circle using the equation:
pi times radius squared.
By the way, I use Visual Studio to make console applications.
These are the steps the program takes:

1. Output some text, like the title, the equation.
2. Get input from the user for the radius and store it in a double(float) variable.
3. Use the equation: pi times radius squared. But replace the radius with the input from the user.
4. Output the results.

Sometimes, an annoying round off error(truncation) sometimes rounds off the decimals and I am frustrated.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double input = NULL;
    const double pi = 3.14;
    cout << "Enter in your radius: " << input << endl;
    cin >> input;
    double acc = pi * pow(2, input);
    
    cout << "The area: " << acc << ". Don't forget to add the measurement type! (example: cm, in)" << endl;

}
```

I used to have a int for the input variable but I changed it to a double(float) variable. Because it is a double(big float), I thought that it would stop the truncation problem. Still the truncation(round off) problem still sometimes occurs.

I wanted it to output a result that is not rounded, and still am getting the round off error

Comment: Are you looking for `setprecision`?

Comment: Please explain what the problem is, show us the output you want and the output you are getting, and reduce the code to the simplest example that recreates the problem.

Comment: Can you show examples with test cases in which *truncation* happens?

Comment: For a minimal example, remove all the promptd and simply assign a value to ’input` (which should be named ’radius`, to better describe its role`). Show the output that you get and describe what you expect.

Comment: It is also worth using a better approximation of **pi**, such as 3.14159265...

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::setprecision() to force to display a set number of digits, for example:

```
#include <iomanip>

// ...

double acc = pi * input * input;
int precision = log10(acc) + 7; // 7 = number of decimals + 1

cout << "The area: " << setprecision(precision) << acc << ". Don't forget to add the measurement type! (example: cm, in)" << endl;
```

Will yield 6 decimal digits.

Ex: for input : 211.123456 will print out

```
The area: 139959.576934. Don't forget to add the measurement type! (example: cm, in)
```

Note that the maximum precision for doubles is 19 digits altogether.